# Designer Workflow - remove current user from person lookup field

Tags: workflow

I have two user lookup fields on my form 'Accepted' and 'Declined'.

I have a workflow, that adds current user to one or another field. But my problem is here, when person has already accepted, but needs to 'Decline' later, then is it possible to check 'Accepted' field for that user and if needed, then remove from there?

I'm using SharePoint 2013 but SharePoint 2010 workflows.

Edit:

So I have 2 fields "Accepted" and "Declined", where I can see people, who have then accepted or declined to invitation to event (event is sent by email).

So I have 2 workflows, what user can activate "Accept" or "Decline". If person has previously accepted, but now needs to decline, then how can I find that person from "Accepted" field and remove from there?

[image]

I hope, this explanation is bit more understandable.

Comment: Question is bit unclear regarding "two user lookup fields"  ... can you re phrase you question please.

Comment: Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any solution with SP 2010 workflow. Using SP 2013 you might be able to resolve. 
Solution is to create dictionary - A of the existing people picker control. Then take current user name in variable, user that initiated the workflow. Create another dictionary - B. Loop all items of dictionary A to find the match of current user in dictionary.
If match not found add in Dictionary - B. 
If found - skip and move to next item (i.e. current user is available in people picker so don't add)
Once all items are looped, assigned Dictionary - B to people picker field.

This is just a thought process, you might need to check if the solution is feasible or not.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thanks for for your confirmation.